# Parallelizing google cloudbuild steps without mangling the build logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build, continuous-testing

Following guidance here: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order

We have split up our build into a multilayer docker image where layers are

1. Install OS and third party deps
2. Install our sources and build (in debug or release depending on docker ARG)
3. Run ci / code coverage

We have tagged the steps in cloudbuild.yaml with docker id's and are using `waitfor` to try to make it so that the `debug` and `release` versions can run *in parallel*.

However, when we do this, the build log is mixed up -- the build logs for release and debug are are jumbled together making it much harder to read. e.g.

```
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded colored v1.7.0
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0m�[91merror: couldn't read /tmp/mobilenode/src/attest/src/ias/../data/AttestationReportSigningCACert.pem: No such file or directory (os error 2)
Step #5 - "build-release":   --> /tmp/mobilenode/src/attest/src/ias/verify.rs:35:7
Step #5 - "build-release":    |
Step #5 - "build-release": 35 |     &[include_str!("../data/AttestationReportSigningCACert.pem")];
Step #5 - "build-release":    |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Step #5 - "build-release": 
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded toml v0.4.10
```

```
[0m�[91m  Downloaded safemem v0.3.0
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded crunchy v0.1.6
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded grpcio-sys v0.4.4
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0m�[91merror: aborting due to previous error
Step #5 - "build-release": 
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0m�[91merror: Could not compile `attest`.
Step #5 - "build-release": warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0m�[91merror: build failed
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0m�[91mmake: *** [src/enclave/target/release/libenclave.so] Error 101
Step #5 - "build-release": �[0mMakefile:90: recipe for target 'src/enclave/target/release/libenclave.so' failed
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded term v0.5.1
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded tiny_http v0.6.2
Step #2 - "build-debug": �[0m�[91m  Downloaded regex v0.1.80
```

Is there a way to configure cloudbuild so that there is a separate log file for each build step? Is the best answer to use a different cloudbuild.yaml for the parallel steps, and skip all this `wait_for` stuff?

Comment: Hey! did you find anything? I am actually having the same behavior required... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721400/is-it-possible-to-start-pubsub-emulator-from-cloud-build-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue, but then I discovered that viewing a build via the `History` under `Cloud Build` in the [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds) will let you view each step individually, or view the entire job, like you're currently seeing (click `Build Summary`, the top entry in the sidebar).
Click on the name of the step in sidebar, each step should be comprised of a number followed by a colon and then the name of the step. The number appears to be based upon the order in which the job appears in your `cloudbuild.yaml`

What you're seeing is a result of the parallelization of your build, as each step that is marked as being able to run concurrently is at a different step in its execution.

[image: Example Build]
You can read more about viewing the Build History using the console [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/view-build-results#console).